# Explode/groupby time series in python for work schedules- Python

Tags: python, pandas

I need to take the following df:

[image]

and convert it to the next df for visualizations:

[image]

I cannot seem to find the correct technique whether it be groupby or explode.  Any thoughts on this?

as requested please see starter code.  I am having trouble getting the number of people working in each 15 minute window to add up.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime


df = pd.DataFrame({'Mon Start': ['6:00', '7:00', '8:00', '9:00'], 'Mon 
End': ['14:30', '15:30', '16:30', '17:30'], 'hours': [8.50, 8.50, 8.50, 
8.50]})


df_transposed_list = []


for i, row in df.iterrows():


start_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(row['Mon Start'], '%H:%M')
end_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(row['Mon End'], '%H:%M')


time_intervals = [start_time + datetime.timedelta(minutes=15*i) for i in 
range(int((end_time - start_time).total_seconds() // 900 + 1))]


num_people = row['hours'] / ((end_time - start_time).total_seconds() / 
3600)


hours_worked = []
 for j in range(len(time_intervals)):
    if time_intervals[j].minute in [0, 15, 30, 45]:
        if j == 0:
            hours_worked.append(min(num_people * 0.25, (15 - 
start_time.minute) / 60))
        elif j == len(time_intervals) - 1:
            hours_worked.append(min(num_people * 0.25, end_time.minute / 
60))
        else:
            if time_intervals[j].hour < 7:
                hours_worked.append(num_people * 0.25)
            elif num_people == 1:
                hours_worked.append(num_people * 0.25)
            elif num_people == 2 and time_intervals[j].hour < 8:
                hours_worked.append(num_people * 0.25)
            elif num_people == 2 and time_intervals[j].hour >= 8:
                hours_worked.append(num_people * 0.5)
            elif num_people == 3 and time_intervals[j].hour < 8:
                hours_worked.append(num_people * 0.25)
            elif num_people == 3 and time_intervals[j].hour >= 8:
                hours_worked.append(num_people * 0.75)
    else:
        hours_worked.append(0)


df_transposed = pd.DataFrame({'Time': [t.strftime('%H:%M') for t in 
time_intervals], 'Hours Worked': hours_worked})


df_transposed_list.append(df_transposed)

df_transposed_all = pd.concat(df_transposed_list, axis=0, 
ignore_index=True)

print(df_transposed_all)
```

Comment: provide example by code or text not image. and how many people in your real dataset? too big? or not?

Comment: Hi Panda- yes i am looking for this to be scaleable.  this is some starter code that I have messed with but I cant get it to add up the number of people workin gin each 15 minute window

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach which works on your slightly modified original sample (first and last row adjusted to cover corner cases):

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Name': ['Phil', 'Tom', 'Sam', 'Randy'],
    'Mon Start': ['6:01', '7:00', '8:00', '9:00'],
    'Mon End': ['14:30', '15:30', '16:30', '17:35'],
})
```

You could try something like the following:

```py
def times(row):
    start, end = row
    times = [*pd.date_range(start.floor('15T'), end.floor('15T'), freq='15T')]
    if start != times[0]:
        times[0] += pd.Timedelta(minutes=15 - start.minute % 15)
    if end != times[-1]:
        times[-1] = end
    return times

for col in 'Mon Start', 'Mon End':
    df[col] = pd.to_datetime(df[col], format='%H:%M')
df['time'] = df[['Mon Start', 'Mon End']].apply(times, axis=1)
df = df[['time']].explode('time')
df['bucket'] = df['time'].dt.floor('15T')
df['minutes'] = df['time'].sub(df['bucket']).where(
    df['time'] != df['bucket'], pd.Timedelta(minutes=15)
).dt.seconds.floordiv(60)
df = (df.assign(bucket=df['bucket'].dt.time)
      .groupby('bucket', as_index=False)['minutes'].sum())
```

The result for the sample looks like:

```
      bucket  minutes
0   06:00:00       14
1   06:15:00       15
2   06:30:00       15
3   06:45:00       15
4   07:00:00       30
5   07:15:00       30
6   07:30:00       30
7   07:45:00       30
8   08:00:00       45
9   08:15:00       45
10  08:30:00       45
11  08:45:00       45
12  09:00:00       60
13  09:15:00       60
14  09:30:00       60
15  09:45:00       60
16  10:00:00       60
17  10:15:00       60
18  10:30:00       60
19  10:45:00       60
20  11:00:00       60
21  11:15:00       60
22  11:30:00       60
23  11:45:00       60
24  12:00:00       60
25  12:15:00       60
26  12:30:00       60
27  12:45:00       60
28  13:00:00       60
29  13:15:00       60
30  13:30:00       60
31  13:45:00       60
32  14:00:00       60
33  14:15:00       60
34  14:30:00       60
35  14:45:00       45
36  15:00:00       45
37  15:15:00       45
38  15:30:00       45
39  15:45:00       30
40  16:00:00       30
41  16:15:00       30
42  16:30:00       30
43  16:45:00       15
44  17:00:00       15
45  17:15:00       15
46  17:30:00        5
```

An alternative approach would be to first build a result dataframe (`res`) with an index that covers all potential time buckets and then use `df.apply` with a function that modifies it accordingly:

```py
def minutes(row, df):
    start, end = row
    start_floor, end_floor = start.floor('15T').time(), end.floor('15T').time()
    m = (start_floor <= df.index) & (df.index <= end_floor)
    df.loc[m, "minutes"] += 15
    if start.time() != start_floor:
        df.at[start_floor, 'minutes'] -= start.minute % 15
    if end.time() != end_floor:
        df.at[end_floor, 'minutes'] -= 15 - end.minute % 15


for col in 'Mon Start', 'Mon End':
    df[col] = pd.to_datetime(df[col], format='%H:%M')
min_start = df['Mon Start'].min().floor('15T')
max_end = df['Mon End'].max().floor('15T')
index = pd.date_range(min_start, max_end, freq='15T').time
res = pd.DataFrame({"minutes": 0}, index=index)
df[['Mon Start', 'Mon End']].apply(minutes, args=(res,), axis=1)
res = res.reset_index().rename(columns={'index': 'bucket'})
```